# FCM Firebase Push Messaging sender ID missmatch

Tags: push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to modernize a website to become a PWA. One part are push notifications. So far so good, I added the manifest with the gcm_sender_id and subscribed to the push service. I tried self-generated vapid-keys or the one provided from google firebase. Snippet:

```
   var reg;
   navigator.serviceWorker.ready
      .then(function(swreg) {
         console.log('SW ready');
         reg = swreg;
         return swreg.pushManager.getSubscription();
      })
      .then(function(sub) {
         console.log('SW ready.then');
         if (sub === null) {
            var vapidPublicKey = 'BEP1z-pU7KfRqXjQGbB_af7YydA1Hxzb3EWDYyb5q44YEflE8RaT0wISdJJnvQlzBkVuC4CupAqU2wm0SxCjxpk';
            // taken^^ from the fcm console under cloud messaging web configuration

            var convertedVapidPublicKey = urlBase64ToUint8Array(vapidPublicKey);
            console.log(convertedVapidPublicKey);
            var retval = reg.pushManager.subscribe({
               userVisibleOnly: true,
               applicationServerKey: convertedVapidPublicKey
            });
            return retval;
         }
         return sub;
      })
      .then(function(newSub) {
         console.log('Received PushSubscription: ', JSON.stringify(newSub));
         return newSub
      })
      .then(function(res) {
         console.log('SW ready.then.then.then');
            if (res.ok) {
               displayConfirmNotification();
            }
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
      });
```

I get a subscription:

```
Received PushSubscription:  {"endpoint":"https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/eU1Mfq-f1So:APA91bEds1D8pio29fNYdMoAQfd_zXcfai7OR_JzppN-Dq5hMhv3_tI9HZHlATBuwBcaPYC6bkmwMXm6IVZ1T83o8r3l8Dyyvxlvy191MjVwc1eKsy8lD1E2sGNaKrZrb5a2qDr9vUi9","expirationTime":null,"keys":{"p256dh":"BLiNeIZqBMTskRwnV5YCtdQFAcbj_-l2fyhOBpcRSOklLy7iv0Ru0XHjJJqOauHeYWk_9rpAjM7lVyVr7_oGHyE","auth":"yXHXHjFu0EiXRXjN8KMEyA"}}
```

So far so good. As far as I understood the process, the browser (in this case Chrome on Android) contacts the google chrome servers and files that subscription. The used vapid key enables firebase to contact the chrome servers, which then trigger the notification through proprietary code, which varies for each browser.

Now I tried to actually use my subscription:

```
$ curl "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/eU1Mfq-f1So:APA91bEds1D8pio29fNYdMoAQfd_zXcfai7OR_JzppN-Dq5hMhv3_tI9HZHlATBuwBcaPYC6bkmwMXm6IVZ1T83o8r3l8Dyyvxlvy191MjVwc1eKsy8lD1E2sGNaKrZrb5a2qDr9vUi9" --request POST --header "TTL: 60" --header "Content-Length: 0" --header "Authorization: key=[server key from fcm console under cloud messaging server key (first entry)"
the key in the authorization header does not correspond to the sender ID used to subscribe this user. Please ensure you are using the correct sender ID and server Key from the Firebase console.
```

I replaced the keys a couple of times. Nothing changes. Google gives me like nothing on this string.

Comment: Seems triggering push notifications with curl doesn't work. I use a php library for that now and have torn that fcm stuff down.

Answer (score 0):

I have node.js express, postgres, angular 8 app.

I got it working by adding the "gcm_sender_id": in the manifest.webmanifest file (or manifest.json
I also used firebase generated public and private keys

your gcm_sender_id is your project id in google cloud or firebase sender id